# Web.Xml file is missing and project works properly

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm learning Spring Security, and followed [this tutorial](http://websystique.com/spring-security/spring-security-4-remember-me-example-with-hibernate/).

I downloaded the project and it worked without any problem. Also I could package its `.war` file and deployed this package to another Tomcat server.

I'm a little bit confused that there is no `web.xml` file in the project. Actually, there aren't any xml files except `pom.xml`. I think we can make configurations in Java files too in Spring.

Ultimately, I want to understand this xml file thing. Why is there no `web.xml` file in the configuration structure of Spring?

Comment: This is Java based config, something which Spring recommends over XML based config. You can find it in documentation at http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this example is using Tomcat 8, which internally supports servlet-api 3.0 & As per servlet 3.0, Now, one can have Servlet, Filter and ServletContextListener in a war file without web.xml .Refer this blog [Servlet3.0](https://blogs.oracle.com/swchan/entry/servlet_3_0_annotations)

Therefore you find no web.xml as part of project.

Comment: Thank you, what if I create web.xml file on my project. Will be any conflict occur? Or shouldn't I create xml file?

Comment: You can still create your web.xml file but you need to be careful since web.xml will override annotation based configuration in some conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Servlet 3.0 onwards you may not require web.xml as most of things is done by annotations. So when you create any dynamic project in Eclipse IDE with Dyamic Module with 3.0 the project also doesn't contain any web.xml file.

Annotations are used to replace this web.xml